# How to create the confirm box in mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, messagebox

I need  to create the confirm box in mvc controller?. Using this 'yes' or 'no' value I need to perform the action in my controller. How we do that?

Sample code:

```
    public ActionResult ActionName(passing value)
        {
             // some code 
             message box here
               if (true)
                     { true code}
              else { else code}
       }
```

Comment: You can do this with Html.ActionLink...

Comment: No. I have some value in my controller using this value i need to perform some action. Another Option: send the the request to the server side and pass the yes or no value to server using this we will perform the some action

Comment: @user279stack1 what have you tried? what code have you done?

Comment: And possible to do with actionlink, too. Also @DanielA.White is right...

Comment: You cannot show message box in controller side, check my updated answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont create confirm box in a Controller, but yes in a View, using JQuery Dialog.
The Controller is already inside the server, so you don't have user interactions there. 
Your View, in the other hand, is the place where the user will choose options, type information, click on buttons etc...
You can intercept the button click, to show that dialog, and only submit the post when the option "Yes" gets clicked.

JQuery Dialog requires *jquery.js*, *jquery-ui.js*, *jquery.ui.dialog.js* scripts referenced in your page.

Example:

```
$(function(){
    $("#buttonID").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('<div title="Confirm Box"></div>').dialog({
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).html("Yes or No question?");
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $.post('url/theValueYouWantToPass');

                },
                'No': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $.post('url/theOtherValueYouWantToPAss');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The .live is not necessary. You can just use .click(function(){...});

Comment: i need to perform the some action in my controller \

Comment: I changed the buttons function. Is that what you need?

Comment: Ok, I saw it, and changed the function again.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "DeleteAction", 
    "Product", 
    new { confirm = true, other_parameter = "some_more_parameter" }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete this product?')" })
```

If user confirm, then link parameter will pass to the controller action method.

```
public ActionResult DeleteAction(bool confirm, string other_parameter)
{
    // if user confirm to delete then this action will fire
    // and you can pass true value. If not, then it is already not confirmed.

    return View();
}
```

**Update**

You can not show message box in controller side. But you can do this like following

```
public ActionResult ActionName(passing value)
{
     // some code 
     message box here
     if (true){ ViewBag.Status = true }
     else { ViewBag.Status = false}

     return View();
}
```

And view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function() {
    var status = '@ViewBag.Status';
    if (status) {
        alert("success");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
}
</script>
```

But these all codes are not elegant way. This is solution of your scenerio.

Comment: Again +1. 42 seconds faster than me

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this with `@Html.ActionLink` as  AliRıza Adıyahşi has commented.

Subscribe to the `onclick` event of the `@Html.ActionLink`

Here is the implementation:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here","ActionName","ControllerName",new { @onclick="return Submit();"})
```

And in javascript write the `confirm` box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Submit() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit ?")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Edit**

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Submit() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit ?")) {
                document.getElementById('anchortag').href += "?isTrue=true";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('anchortag').href += "?isTrue=false";
            }
            return true;
        }
</script>

@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "Somemethod", "Home", new { @onclick = "return Submit();", id = "anchortag" })
```

Now in your controller do some operations based on the `isTrue` querystring

```
public ActionResult Somemethod(bool isTrue)
        {
            if (isTrue)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that AliRıza Adıyahşi's solution works well.

You can also customize the the message. In my case we're using MVC and Razor, so I could do this:

```
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", 
    "DeleteTag", new { id = t.IDTag }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete the tag " + @t.Tag + "?')" })
</td>
```

Which showed a dialog with a specific record named in it. Might also be possible to give the confirm dialog a title, haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteBlog", new {id = @post.PostId})" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure want to delete blog?');">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete
```