# I want a modal after a click the button send in a form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

When I click the button send on a form it opens a modal, but where I am lost is about how to send those values to the method in my controller after I click the ok button on the modal.

I already know how to open the modal after I click send on the button form but when the modal shows up asking "are you sure you want to create ....?" and I send yes I want to send those values to the method in my controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Aplication</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select name="appID">
                <option disabled class="font-weight-bold">Select App</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Application)
                {
                    <option value="@item.ID" customAttribute="@item.ID">
                        @item.Application_Name
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Assignee</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select name="approverID">
                <option disabled class="font-weight-bold">Select Assignee</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Assigne)
                {
                    <option value="@item.ID" customAttribute="@item.ID">
                        @item.Email_Address
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Region</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select name="regionID">
                <option disabled class="font-weight-bold">Select Region</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Region)
                {
                    <option value="@item.ID" customAttribute="@item.ID">
                        @item.Region_Name
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Severity</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select name="severity">
                <option disabled class="font-weight-bold">Select Severity</option>
                <option value"1">1</option>
                <option value"2">2</option>
                <option value"3">3</option>
                <option value"4">4</option>
                <option value"5">5</option>
                <option value"6">6</option>
                <option value"7">7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="fileupload">Attachment</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="file" name="document" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea name="description" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-dark btn-lg">Create</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <button type="reset" class="btn-dark btn-lg" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>

}
</div>



<div class="modal align-content-center" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="text-danger">Are you sure you want to create this workflow?</p>
            <div id="result">


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Go()">YES</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Go() {
            $('#myModal').click();
        }
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create the confirm box in mvc controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548073/how-to-create-the-confirm-box-in-mvc-controller)

Comment: Where is the modal and yes button? Can you please update the question. Only plan html is showing here. Can you please past the modal code. In the modal you can handle the button click then can call ajax to send the data at server site.

Comment: Your Go function is not doing anything special but only clicking the modal.